# The minimum and maximum limits are displayed while printing an integer array ( frustrating me)

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I am writing a program to display the elements of an integer array in random order and deleting the called value.
I am on the last phase and while printing the array the lower and upper limits of the array are being printed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

srand(time(0));
int j,i,x,y,l=1,c=1;
int arr[10][9]={};
for(j=0;j<10;j++)
{
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        arr[j][i]=c;
        c++;
        
    }
}
for(j=0;j<10;j++)
{
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
    //  cout<<arr[j][i]<<" ";
    }
    //cout<<"\n";
}
int t=0;
while(l!=0)
{
    l=0;
    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<9;i++)
        {   
            l+=arr[j][i];
        }
        
    }   
    x=rand()%10;
    y=rand()%9;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    while(x!=j)
    {   
        j++;
        while(y!=i)
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    //cout<<" \n "<<x<<" "<<y;
    
        if(arr[0][1]+arr[0][2]+arr[0][3]+arr[0][4]+arr[0][5]+arr[0][6]+arr[0][7]+arr[0][8]+arr[0][9]==0)
        {
            
                cout<<"\n"<<arr[j][i];
                arr[j][i]=0;
        }
        
        else
        {
                cout<<"\n"<<arr[j-1][i-1];
                arr[j-1][i-1]=0;
        }
                
     c=0;
    //cout<<"\n"<<arr[j-1][i-1]<<"\n ";
    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            while(arr[j][i]==0)
            {
                i++;
                while(i==0)
                {
                    j++;
                    c++;
                }
                
            }
            //cout<<arr[j][i]<<" ";
        }
    //  cout<<"\n";
    }
    /*for(j=0;j<9;j++)
    
    {
        for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        {   
        //  cout<<arr[j][i]<<" ";
        }
        //cout<<"\n";
    }*/
    t++;
    if(t>=700)
    break;
}
for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<9;i++)
        {   
            cout<<arr[j][i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }       
 }
```

and the output is below

It is disturbing because I need to scroll a lot to get something of my use.
If u need more information it is a program from a board game TAMBOLA which is similar to BINGO random numbers are picked between 1 and 90 and is a luck based game.

```
74
59
13
57
44
3
19
25
63
35
20
79
33
55
22
0
71
80
21
38
77
4200155
78
31
9
8
69
0
0
62
0
27
15
54
24
17
0
0
2
29
0
67
72
50
30
0
0
4200155
0
61
18
66
0
0
0
4200155
4200155
0
12
43
0
48
5
0
0
47
0
0
4200155
4200155
65
0
39
0
34
28
60
49
0
0
4200155
0
0
0
0
4200155
0
4200155
23
0
64
0
0
0
0
0
0
4200155
0
0
0
76
0
0
11
4200155
0
41
7
4200155
4200155
0
0
0
0
14
4200155
0
0
0
0
0
0
32
0
0
0
0
37
0
0
0
..........

 I hope someone can help.
```

Comment: Hint: use `arr[j][i]=c++` and omit the next line.

Comment: plz specify the line number or something else to get a reference. thanks :)

Comment: Line 18 (`arr[j][i]=c`).

Comment: thank u will let u know if it works

Comment: Sorry but I think you've misunderstood me. That's just a *suggestion*. Something else is causing the problem.

Comment: oh ok
anyways the issue is now resolved :)